# N balls having M different colors in a box, how many times do I need to pick to get one particular color?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

There are $N$ balls of $M$ different colors in a box i.e $c_1$ balls of color $1$ and so on. $c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_M=N$, $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_M$ are known. We are looking for a ball of a particular color, say, $j$.The balls are picked from the box randomly, and if the color of the ball picked up say $i$ is such that, $i \ne j$, all the balls of color $i$ disappear. How many times do I need to pick to get a ball of color $j$ on average?

Comment: Are the balls put back in the box after a draw ?

Comment: I don't get the bit about the disappearing balls.  Are you saying that "if you are looking for a red ball, and you draw a blue one, all the blue ones are removed from the box?"

Comment: @lulu yes, exactly

Comment: Just to be completely clear:  if there are only two colors in the box, then either you get the right one the first time, or you are guaranteed to get it the next time.  Right?

Comment: Yes, if there are two colors, then what you said is correct.But, say if you are looking for a red ball, and you draw a blue one (these are the only colors), this counts as having picked twice.

Comment: Got it.  So if there are colors #1 and #2 and you want #1, then you get it in 1 turn with probability $\frac {c_1}{c_1+c_2}$ and in 2 turns with probability $\frac {c_2}{c_1+c_2}$.  Hence the expected number of turns is  $$\frac {c_1}{c_1+c_2}+2\frac {c_2}{c_1+c_2}=\frac {c_1+2c_2}{c_1+c_2} $$

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate even though it had an accepted answer and even though the other question is newer, because the questions are the same and the answer given for the other one is clearly better. (See [Which question is the duplicate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/172855): "keep the question with the best collection of answers, and close the other one as a duplicate")

Comment: As this question came up three times in different forms in a short while, I'd be interested to know how you came up with it.

Comment: [Code Chef challenge problem](https://www.codechef.com/SEPT15/problems/THEGAME), I'm locking until the contest is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that there is a simple closed formula for this, but there is a fairly simple way to compute it recursively.

Let's say we are looking for color $1$, just to be specific. For any data $\{c_i\}_{1}^m$, let E[{c_i}] be the expected number of turns required to find color 1.  We see that:

$$E[\{c_i\}]=\frac{c_1}{\sum {c_i}}\,1+\sum_{j=2}^{j=m}\frac{c_j}{\sum {c_i}}(E[\{c_1,c_2, ...,\hat {c_j},...c_m\}]+1)$$ Where, as usual, the $\hat {c_j}$ means that this term is deleted from the data.

this is very easy to automate.  Perhaps it can be solved in closed form, though the shifting probabilities make that look a little daunting.

Comment: It's okay I need to do that in a computer program anyway, so a recursive solution is fine.Thank you.

Comment: Phew.  If $m$ is large I'd do it from the boundary in.  We've already done it for two colors, so add in all possible third colors.  Then all possible fourth colors, and so on. Keeps the bookkeeping very clean.

Comment: There's an elegant solution in an answer to [the question that I closed this as a duplicate of](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428122).

Comment: @joriki Oh, thank you!  Missed this principle completely.  Seems like it might have wider use.

Answer (score 0):

The closed form seems hard. A computational alternative is:

- Let $P(x,j)$ be the probability that we pick a ball of $j$ th kind for the first time in $x+1$ th picking.
- Let $S_j$ be the set of solutions of $x_1+\dots +x_{j-1} +x_{j+1}+\dots+x_m=x$ with the restriction that $0\le x_i \le c_i \ \forall \, 1\le i \le m \, , \,  i\ne j$ (Can be generated by a recursive program.)
- Let $z_{j,l}:=\langle y_1,\dots,y_{j-1},y_{j+1},\dots,y_m \rangle \in S_j$. Then, the probability that $y_1$ balls of type-1, $y_2$ balls of type-2 and so on were selected out of a total of $x$ balls is $$P(x,j,l):=\binom{x}{y_1,\dots,y_{j-1},y_{j+1},\dots,y_m}\frac{\prod_{i=1;i\ne j}^{M}(c_i)(c_i-1)\cdots (c_i-y_i+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots (N-x-1)}$$
  Note that we are taking into account the order in which the balls are picked. Elements are $S_j$ are indexed by $l$. Make sure that the recursive program gives output in some canonical order.
- Hence, $P(x,j)=\sum_{l=1}^{|S_j|}P(x,j,l)\cdot \frac{c_j}{N-x}$ and the expected value is $\sum_{x=1}^{N}x \cdot P(x,j)$

Comment: There's an elegant solution in an answer to [the question that I closed this as a duplicate of](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428122).