# How to find expectation in this weird problem? (Pretty Interesting)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, dynamic-programming

There are $N$ wires.

The $i^\text{th}$ wire has $P_i$ bulbs.

The bulbs are connected in series, so if you break a bulb, all the bulbs on the wire go out.

A person can break any **lit** bulb with equal probability. (Broken/Off bulbs are not included in the sample space.)

One of the wires has a parallel connection. (That means if the bulb on this wire is broken, the other bulbs still glow).

A person wants to find this wire (by breaking bulbs). If he hits a bulb in the parallel wire connection (and thereby identifies the wire) on the $X^\text{th}$ try, what is the **expectation of $X$**?

The total number of bulbs is $T$.

Comment: Point of clarification:  are you choosing uniformly among the wires or among the bulbs?  In my solution below I assume the former, but I realized that this is not specified in the problem.

Comment: I have deleted my answer on the theory that you probably meant that we are choosing uniformly in the bulbs (thus if $P_1=2P_2$ you are twice as likely to select the first wire on the first attempt).  I think this point should be clarified in the question, though.  If this interpretation is correct, then a recursive solution (to an equivalent problem) may be found here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421863/n-balls-having-m-different-colors-in-a-box-how-many-times-do-i-need-to-pick-to/1421892?noredirect=1#comment2896099_1421892

Comment: We are choosing uniformly among the bulbs. I think it's clear though.. And yeah, it exactly that question in the link youu shared.. But I didn't really understand the solution.Could you please explain little more? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure...what makes the problem a challenge (at least as far as finding a closed form goes) is that the probabilities keep shifting.  The recursion just looks at one turn...let's say you want wire #1.  Then you get it with probability $\frac {P_1}{\sum P_i}$ in which case the answer, along that path, is $1$.  If you miss it, then say you get the $j^{th}$ wire ($i≥2$).  The probability of that happening is $\frac {P_j}{\sum P_i}$.  Once you have done that you are now back at the start, only you have $1$ fewer wire and the number of bulbs is reduced by $P_j$.  You have already chosen once so...

Comment: ...along this path the answer is $1+E[\{P_1, P_2, ...\hat {P_j}, ...P_N\}$] , where the hat means that that data is excised from the problem. This is extremely easy to automate.  it is easy to sort it out fully if there are a small number of wires.  Like I said in the other problem, I doubt there is a closed formula...but who knows?  Might be worth looking at a lot of cases to see if a pattern emerges.

Comment: Does E[{P1,P2,...Pj^,...PN}] mean expextation of X assuming Pj doesn't exist? Also, is this a standard problem? Where can I find the derivation of that?

Comment: Yes, as to the definition.  No as to it being standard.  At least, I have never seen it before.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, but I find it kinda difficult understanding it.. If it's not too much trouble, could you please show me how you got this?

Comment: It's induction (or backwards induction). One wire is not interesting.  Two wires...either you get it the first time ($prob=\frac {P_1}{P_1+P_2}$) or you get it the second ($prob=\frac {P_2}{P_1+P_2}$.  Thus the answer is $$\frac {P_1}{P_1+P_2}^*1+\frac {P_1}{P_1+P_2}^*2$$. Now do three wires.  Either you get it on the first try, $prob=\frac {P_1}{P_1+P_2+P_3}$ or you are down to one of three cases with two wires.  But you've done the two wire cases!  Write this out and you'll see the formula in this case.  Still perfectly possible to write it down explicitly.  Now do four....

Comment: ....still not horrible.  You have 4 three wire possibilities, then 6 two wire cases.  Similarly, starting with five wires gives you 5 four wire states, $\binom {5}{3}=10$ three wire states, $10$ two wire states (so $25$ states all in all) if you count the initial $N$ wire state and the $N$ possible one wire states then you are delaing with $2^N-1$ states, so the program grows exponentially. Not ideal.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! :) 
Just wish there was a less complex solution to this :3

Comment: From a programming point of view, this is pretty simple.  I entirely agree that it doesn't give a very good feel for the final answer.  Like I say...I'd recommend trying a bunch of, say, 5 wire examples.  Maybe a pattern emerges!  As a rule, problems where the probabilities are badly path dependent tend not to have good closed solutions.  Think of blackjack, say...in casinos they use multiple decks and shuffle frequently, so the card supply is fairly constant...but in casual play the math is very different (it matters a lot if you have discarded a lot of tens).