# Expected Value for number of draws

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

There are $n$ types of balls in an urn; $a$ balls of type $1$ , $b$ balls of type $2$ , $c$ balls of type $3$ and so on. Now balls are drawn until a ball of type $1$ is obtained with condition that if a ball of type $i$ is drawn at any moment ( $i \neq 1$ ) then all balls of type $i$ will be removed from the urn.
What is the expected number of draws done? (In one draw, all balls of that particular type are removed)

My approach for $n = 3$ is like:

expectation value = $a/(a+b+c)+2(ba/(a+b+c)(a+c)+ca/(a+b+c)(a+b))+3(bca/(a+b+c)(a+c)a+cba/(a+b+c)(a+b)a)$

But it's messy , is there any general form for n type of balls ?

Comment: Interesting, this question has suddenly come up three times within a few days in different forms (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428237) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421863)) -- I'd be interested to know how you came up with it.

Comment: [Code Chef challenge problem](https://www.codechef.com/SEPT15/problems/THEGAME), I'm locking until the contest is over.

Answer (score 2):

Prob(Balls of type $2$ are removed)=$b/(a+b)$.
Average number of draws  = $$1+\sum_i\frac{b_i}{a+b_i}$$

Comment: Hi Michael -- just to let you know I just closed two other questions as a duplicate of this one. No one had come up with this elegant answer there -- so if you'd care to expand on it a little, three questions would be benefitting at the same time :-)

Comment: Unless there is some very clever cancellation going on here, I don't see how this works. In particular, why is the division not by the *total* number of balls?

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you.  Seems like an approach that might have wider applicability.

Comment: @Ian Does the first $b_i$ ball appear before the first $a$ ball?  The other colours don't come into it.

Comment: Can you explain the answer as the contest is now over ?